# Set title of the WordPress page with two different colors

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, fonts

The title in my WordPress is of two words (say "The Company" for example). Right now the default color is Blue. But I want the "The" portion in the above example to be Grey. I used the font tag and set it as **`<font color="grey">The</font> Company`** in the site title Input box. In the preview page it is showing correctly, but when I visit my page , it is showing as

**`<font color="grey">The</font> Company`**

including the tags. How to modify? I'm using mindfulness theme in WordPress
(similar kind of) if someone throws a light on option two of [this page](http://www.rickrduncan.com/wordpress/customize-wordpress-widget-titles).

A briefly describing image:

[image: The Company - site title]

Comment: What theme are you using, or are these custom modifications? I haven't seen the `<font>` tag used for ages! Why don't you use CSS and classes?

Comment: birgire ... I agree ... Actually the theme I am using is displaying a input text box for the title to set. Actually that is linked in anchor tag. I have changed the style.css but no required results. I think I have to modify the php content as it is displaying the html tags included.

Comment: *Mindfulness* is a primary theme, so I gave an answer instead for the *Twenty Twelve* theme. Hopefully you can adjust it to your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### How to target specific words in the blog title of the *Twenty Twelve* theme?

You can try the following, it works for the *Twenty Twelve* theme:

```
/**
 * Wrap the first word of the blog title with the <span>...</span> tag.
 * Assumes the Twenty Twelve theme.
 *
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25096093/2078474
 */

add_filter( 'body_class', 
    function( $class )
    {
        add_filter( 'bloginfo', 'so_25094932_modify_first_word', 10, 2 );
        return $class;
    }
);

function so_25094932_modify_first_word( $output, $show )
{
    static $counter = 0;

    // Target the "name" part:
    if( 'name' === $show )
    {
        // Target the second instance:
        if( 2 === ++$counter )
        {
            remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

            // Modify the first word of the blog title:
            $title = explode( ' ', $output );
            if( count( $title ) > 0 )
            {
                $title[0] = sprintf( '<span>%s</span>', $title[0] );
            }
            $output = join( ' ', $title );                      
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

where we use the `bloginfo` filter to target only the *second* instance of the blog name, counted from the `<body>` tag.

Then we can target the *span* tag with CSS:

```
h1.site-title span{
    color: red;
}
```

**Example:**

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Blog title modified]

It should be possible to adjust our code snippet to other themes as well.

I hope this helps.

Comment: could u please explain where and how to do this. When i access the theme php files, there is comment in it as "DO NOT EDIT these under any circumstances." In which php file should i try editing the above code? And should i change the bloginfo part?

Comment: You can add this into the `functions.php` file in your current theme directory or make your own plugin. We might need to adjust this to your theme.

Comment: ..yeah I edited functions.php, but it was futile. It is not showing the desired output. As i said the title is in anchor tag already which is in site-title class.  (.site-title a {
color: #E28913) This is the CSS of it. Can u please explain more clearly the steps you followed to achieve that. What and where to edit and what to change. Thanks a lot in advance .. :)

Comment: Here's how I matched the counter for the 2012 theme: I located the `body_class()` function in the `<body>` tag in the `header.php` theme file and from there I counted the number of `bloginfo('name')` or `get_bloginfo('name', 'display')` instances, all the way into the place where the title is displayed. For the 2012 theme I counted two, so I used that in this code line: `if( 2 === ++$counter )`. This is the first step. Then view your HTML source to see if the span was wrapped around the first title word.

Answer (score 1):

To do so you have to change the style.css that controls your design | theme.

**Edit CSS from wordpress:**

Login to WordPress, not sure which version you're running, but you should have a section  called Themes or Design. From there choose Theme Editor. There will be a list of all the files you can edit, the CSS stylesheet should be named style.css.

You will have to have write access in order to edit it from within WP admin.

**Otherwise you will have to find the file via FTP on your website, download it to your computer, edit it, and then upload it back to your site.**

**Edit CSS the way you want it:**

```
<span id="the">The</span>
<span id="company">Company</span>
<style>

#the{color: #0033CC;} //refers to blue.
#company{color:#CCCCCC;} //refers to grey.

</style>
```

There is also a fiddle for you to test it:

**[JSFIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shaharlini/j22Vt/)**

GoodLuck!

Comment: Linial, Thanks alot. But this wont work as theme demands to set the title in input box. I tried with all tags changing its CSS, but no desired result. The HTML tags are always appearing.

Comment: Could you please attach a Photo of the result?
And maybe more of your code?

Comment: I'm just assuming that it will not work on the input box, you might want to add some RAW HTML for that to be as Title, it looks like that the input box will print out everything you type in it, so when you <span>the</span .. it will type those tags inside.

What I would do is: add RAW HTML content, for the Header, and change it's color from CSS, since your request is not frequent to Wordpress.

GoodLuck

Comment: Can u please elaborate on -- What would you edit in that input box, so as to remove the html tags inputted in?